# How code a moving current location in Google maps HTML5 code examples?

Tags: html, google-maps, maps

We are using Google MAPS API o a HTML5 code page, and want the current location to follow when showing the page on a mobile. But can't find the code for update the location when the mobile is moving?

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the current position using [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Watching_the_current_position)